# Asp.net error The type 'typeName' exists in both

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've read and test similar questions here but don't solve my problem.
I'm working asp.net webform and I've added a class to App_data folder and change build action to compile to use the public class in my site.master.

now in site.master I have this error
I've test many solutions like clear temp folder or rebuild project but didn't solve.

Note: when I move my class into other folders (except App_data) there isnt any problem but I want that it be in App_data.

Here is a screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm3Jg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it
My problem was that I have started a new project in visual studio , I should start a new website!!